# Algorithm design manual solutions error?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I've read about Big O notation from many sources, including [Skiena](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) and the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) entry, the [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example) section of which states:

> In typical usage, the formal definition of O notation is not used
>   directly; rather, the O notation for a function f(x) is derived by the
>   following simplification rules:
>
> - If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.
> - If f(x) is a product of several factors, any `constants` (terms in the product that do not depend on x) are `omitted`.

The [solution](http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.2) to [problem 2.2](http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/Algo-analysis-TADM2E) is O((n^3)/3).  Shouldn't the "/3" be omitted, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. 1/3 is a constant, and therefore should omitted.

Answer (score 4):

The constants do not need to be omitted, they just don't carry any information - O(n^3) is the same as O(n^3 / 3). You'll note that the quoted passage discusses typical usage, not rigorous requirements.

Looking at the specific answer, the solution is asymptotically equivalent to n^3 / 3. While not formally any different than O(n^3), I'd guess the idea is to provide more specific information by giving O(n^3 / 3).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation     read the example section. I now is no difference, but if it is represented as Big O, the rules should be respected.

Comment: @croisharp Read the definitions, not the examples. Constants do *not* need to be eliminated.

Comment: Multiplying a function by a constant can not affect
its asymptotic behavior, because we can multiply the bounding constants in the
Big Oh analysis of c · f(n) by 1/c to give appropriate constants for the Big Oh
analysis of f(n). Thus:
O(c · f(n)) → O(f(n)).     
The algorithm Design Manual, page 40. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Comment: @croisharp Sounds like we're in perfect agreement. O(c · f(n)) → O(f(n)) *and* O(f(n)) → O(c · f(n)); the constants might as well be eliminated, but don't have to be.

Comment: Ok, it is not a must, but it should be omitted as Daniel said.

Answer (score 4):

Not *must*, positive constant factors are allowed in O-notation. They are just pointless and therefore *should* be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, to be proper, O(n^3 /3) (i.e., O(1/3 * n^3)) should have the 1/3 coefficient omitted from the final answer. This is because the 1/3 component of the expression is trivial with extremely large n. This would be a good opportunity to edit Wikipedia and make the correction.

Answer (score 0):

**Let me give an example.**

```
suppose we have function,
                f(n)=1/3 * (4n^3) + 4n^2+ 1


 lets gather all the facts...

 we know that , 
          for all sufficient large value of n>=1              
              1/3 * (4n^3) <= 1/3 *  4n^3

          for all sufficient large value of n>=1
               4n^2 <= 1/3 * 12n^3

      and similarly, for all sufficent large value of n>=1
                  1 <= 1/3 * 5n^3

  thus we can conclude that,                  
   1/3 * (4n^3) + 4n^2+ 1  <= 1/3 * 4n^3 + 1/3 * 12n^3+1/3 * 5n^3   , where n >=1

  lets simplify it,   
           1/3 * (4n^3) + 4n^2+ 1  <= (1/3) * 21n^3  
                            f(n)   <= (1/3) * 21n^3 
                            f(n)   <= ((1/3)*21)*n^3
                            f(n)   <= (7)*n^3    
                            f(n)   = O(n^3) , where c=7 and n0=1

 if we don't include 1/3 in c than, 
                            f(n)   <= (1/3) * 21n^3
                            f(n)   <=  (21)*(n^3 /3)
                            f(n)   = O(n^3 /3), where c=21 and n0=1

 so the constant value 'c' will be changed.
```